# Accelerating polygon dissolution with rgeos

Tags: r, topology, geos

I have a list of 300 Spatial Polygons Data Frames in `R` that I wish to dissolve geometrically. Each `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` contains about 500 polygons. 
I have tried the functions `gUnion` and `gUnaryUnion` included in the rgeos package.

Processing with `gUnion` is done this way:

```
dissolved <- gUnion(tilelist[[1]], tilelist[[2]], byid=FALSE, id=NULL)
for(k in 1:length(tilelist)){
  dissolved <- gUnion(dissolved, tilelist[[k]], byid=FALSE, id=NULL)
}
```

And processing with `gUnaryUnion` is done like this:

```
flatpolygon=list()
for(k in 1:length(tilelist)){
  flatpolygon[[k]] <- tilelist[[k]]@polygons
}
mypoly <- SpatialPolygons(unlist(flatpolygon))
final <- gUnaryUnion(mypoly, id = NULL)
```

Both of these methods require several hours to perform the dissolution (on a Win 64, 16 GB RAM). Any algorithmic ideas on how to improve the processing time?

Comment: What is the output of `version_GEOS0()` or `version_GEOS()` ?

Comment: The output of `version_GEOS()` is `"3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8"`

Comment: You have a recent version of GEOS so is not related to that. But without your data or similar data is difficult to tell. What about using `maptools::unionSpatialPolygons` and try to use `gpclib` (parameter `avoidGEOS = TRUE`) and compare the two options

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, according to documentation, the `unionSpatialPolygons` function in `maptools` uses `gUnaryUnion` from `rgeos`. Also, I would like to avoid using `gpclib` because of its restrictive license.

Comment: Ok, so we have to test if this performance is directly related to `GEOS` or `R` (I/O overhead ?). Do you have access to `PostGIS` or `SpatiaLite` or `GRASS` ?

Comment: Yes, I have access to both `PostGIS` and `GRASS`.